# Component Checkbox not set (vue, vee validate)

Tags: vue.js

My component Checkbox was working properly for unitialized forms (sign up) including a required rule validation. I moved on to Edit User form and I failed to initialize it. The boolean property is set but it has no effect - checkbox is not checked. You can try it yourself here: https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-tree-6g8qy. I have googled already and there were advices to set v-model to some property. But I use a component with vee-validate and v-model needs to emit a signal.

Checkbox.vue

```vue
<template>
    <ValidationProvider
        tag="span"
        v-model="innerValue"
        :vid="vid"
        :rules="rules"
        :name="name || label"
        v-slot="{ errors, required }"
    >
        <input :id="identifier" v-model="innerValue" :value="identifier" type="checkbox" ref="input">
        <label :for="identifier">
            <span>{{label}}</span>
        </label>
    </ValidationProvider>
</template>

<script>
    import {ValidationProvider} from "vee-validate";

    export default {
        props: {
            vid: {
                type: String,
                default: undefined
            },
            identifier: {
                type: String,
                default: undefined
            },
            name: {
                type: String,
                default: ""
            },
            label: {
                type: String,
                default: ""
            },
            rules: {
                type: [Object, String],
                default: ""
            },
            value: {
                type: null,
                default: ""
            },
            checked: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false
            }
        },
        components: {
            ValidationProvider
        },
        data: () => ({
            innerValue: null
        }),
        watch: {
            innerValue(value) {
                this.$emit("input", value);
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

store.js

```vue
export default new Vuex.Store({
    actions: {
        GET_USER_PROFILE_BY_ID: async (context, payload) => {
            return {
                driving: {
                    vehicles: ['car']
                }
            };
        },
    },
});
```

App.vue

```vue
<ValidationObserver ref="form" v-slot="{ passes, invalid }">
    <form @submit.prevent="passes(submitForm)">
        <label for="vehicle">Vehicles</label>
        <Checkbox v-model="car" label="car" name="vehicle" identifier="car"/>
        <Checkbox v-model="bus" label="bus" name="vehicle" identifier="bus"/>
        <Checkbox v-model="van" label="van" name="vehicle" identifier="van"/>
        <Checkbox v-model="truck" label="truck" name="vehicle" identifier="truck"/>

        <div>
            <button type="button" :disabled="invalid" @clicked="submitForm()">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</ValidationObserver>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "App",
        components: {
            Checkbox,
            ValidationObserver
        },
        data: () => ({
            car: null,
            bus: null,
            van: null,
            truck: null,
            error: null,
            success: null
        }),
        created() {
            this.getProfile(1);
        },
        methods: {
            async getProfile(id) {
                try {
                    const response = await this.$store.dispatch("GET_USER_PROFILE_BY_ID", {
                        id
                    });
                    console.log(response);
                    this.car = response.driving.vehicles.includes("car");
                    this.bus = response.driving.vehicles.includes("bus");
                    this.van = response.driving.vehicles.includes("van");
                    this.truck = response.driving.vehicles.includes("truck");
                    console.log(this.car);
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You lost the `<script>` tag in the last fragment. Use blocks to specify the language of the code - syntax coloring helps a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've understood your problem correctly, [this sandbox should help](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-fog-hizlt).

A summary of what I've changed:

Got rid of `:value="identifier"` on Checkbox.vue which would have been conflicting with v-model (since v-model is just a :value and @input).

Replaced innerValue data and it's watcher with a `:checked = value` and `@input="$emit('input', $event)"`. Since I got rid of innerValue and you shouldn't update a prop, it just emits instead to get the value.

Got rid of prop "checked" because it wasn't used

I would advise keeping checkbox values either true or false instead of null, since that's the only two values they can have.

EDIT:

I've forked the code from your updated sandbox which is available [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-zhukovsky-2h1xf).

Replaced innerValue with value because innerValue doesn't exist -- fixed all the console errors.

Changed the emit value from $event to $event.target.checked -- so it emits a true or false rather than the whole event

I had to add `:value="value"` back on the checkbox because apparently VeeValidate needs a v-model or a :value to serve as a hint, documentation found [here](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/guide/basics.html#validation-provider).

Comment: This is a partial success. The checkbox is now checked - thanks. Console is full or errors of undefined innervalue - it is referenced from <ValidationProvider  v-model="innerValue".

Comment: Another issue is that I cannot uncheck the checkbox now. And the last issue is that the required validation does not work as well. I have enhanced my sandbox with a consent.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an edit, that should solve your problems